# how can i find two consecutive characters without worrying about spaces between them

Tags: php, arrays, string, str-replace

i want to find the character 1 and # in a string and then explode. i can use the explode. my problem is i don't know how much space can occur between these two characters.

```
// This is what is how my string looks / may look like
1                #first                  (dog)
1 #second                                (cat)
1           #third                       (dog)

// this is what i want to do 
$return = str_ireplace('1 #', ',1 #', $string); // this line is the problem because it only searches for 1 # and not 1    #
$return = explode(","$return);

// this is how i want my output
Array
(
  [0] => 1                #first                  (dog)
  [1] => 1 #second                                (cat)
  [2] => 1           #third                       (dog)
)
```

Comment: [`preg_replace('~1\s*#~', ',$0', $string);`](https://ideone.com/Xq8Pei)? If `1` is always at the string start, add `^`: `'~^1\s*#~'`

Comment: prorbaly look at regex for this or if the space is not actually needed remove the space before doing your check

Comment: Do you mean you just have a 3-line  string? Why not explode with a `\n`ewline? Or an `\n` after which there is `1`, spaces, `#`? `preg_split('~\n(?=1\h*#)~', $string)`?

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions were pretty much made for what you need. You'd simply replace

```
$return = str_ireplace('1 #', '1 #', $string);
```

with

```
$return = preg_replace('/1 +#/', '1 #', $string);
```

and that'll do what you want it to.

As for a short explanation of the regex:

The `/` at the beginning and the end delimit the beginning and end of the regex. The actual regex can be anything in between those slashes. They don't have to be slashes, in fact - any non-whitespace character can be a delimiter, but keep in mind that any occurrence of this character *within* your regex must be escaped with a backslash. The reason for these delimiters is that the regex can be followed by various **modifiers** to change how your regex behaves, such as `i` for case-insensitive search.

The `1` matches just what it says on the tin - a single numeral one. It matches this anywhere in the string you're searching. The space also matches a literal space character, and the `#` matches a literal pound sign.

The `+` indicates that the preceding character may not occur just once, but *one or more* times. So `/a+/` will match on `a`, or on `aa`, or on `aaaaaaa`, etc.

So basically this regex matches any string containing a one followed by *one or more* spaces, followed by a pound sign, and replaces that whole thing with the string `'1 #'`.

Regexes are a more complex beast than I can explain here, but basically any time you don't want to match an *exact* string but a string with parts that may vary between matches, a regex is probably what you need.

You can check http://regexone.com/ for a decent primer on regexes, they're incredibly useful. Want to figure out if something could be a valid postal code? Regex. Want to see if something looks like a phone number? Regex. Want to know if a password contains enough characters, contains at least one character, at least one number, and does not contain the username? Regex. The possibilities are endless.

Answer (score 0):

You could change this line to remove all the spaces:

```
$return = str_ireplace('1#', ',1 #', str_ireplace(' ','',$string));
```

Comment: i do not want to remove the spaces look at  my desired output . i edited my question

Answer (score 0):

You can use [preg_split(..)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) function on your string as below:

```
$str = "1                #first                  (dog)
1 #second                                (cat)
1           #third                       (dog)";
$regex = "/1\s*#/";
$keywords = preg_split($regex, $str, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
print_r($keywords);
```

**EDIT**
To capture also the delimiter itself (not sure why) use below :

```
$regex = "/1\s*#/";
$strFixed = preg_replace($regex, "|\\0", $str);
$tokens = array_filter(explode('|', $strFixed));
print_r($tokens);
```

What the code does:

- Line 1 defines a regex to search for a string that matches
  `1space(s)#`
- Line 2 inserts `|` as a character to separate
- Line 3 explodes on the `|` delimiter and filters empty elements
- Line 4 prints the array

The output is

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1                #first                  (dog)
    [2] => 1 #second                                (cat)
    [3] => 1           #third                       (dog)
)
```

Comment: your code works but the array it builds is not my desired output ..please check my edited version of the question.  your array removes the 1 and the spaces . but i nedd the one and the spaces

Comment: You can add **PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE** flag to include delimiter in your output.

Comment: could you please please supply me with an example

Comment: alomost there , i checked your edit but his is it outputs now `Array
(
    [0] => first                  (dog)

    [1] => second                                (cat)

    [2] => third                       (dog)
)` it destroys the 1 and the spaces between 1 and #

Comment: Let me know if it helps

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

You could do that with a combination of `array_filter()`, `preg_split()` and `array_map()`... plus You may as well 
[quick-test it here...](https://eval.in/625027).

```
    <?php
        $str        = "1                #first                  (dog)";
        $str       .= "1 #second                                (cat)";
        $str       .= "1           #third                       (dog)";

        $return     = array_filter(preg_split("#\)#", $str));
        $return     = array_map(function($string){
            return $string .= ")";
        }, $return);

        var_dump($return);
        // PRODUCES::
        array (size=3)
          0 => string '1                #first                  (dog)' (length=46)
          1 => string '1 #second                                (cat)' (length=46)
          2 => string '1           #third                       (dog)' (length=46)
```

Comment: i have one string but you are using 3 strings. this is what that code returns. which is not what i want `Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => #first
    [2] => (dog)
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => #second
    [2] => (cat)
)
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => #third
    [2] => (dog)
)`

Answer (score 0):

How about that one:

```
$str = '1                #first                  (dog)
1 #second                                (cat)
1           #third                       (dog)';

preg_match_all('/(1[^1]+)/', $yourStr, $matches);
$matches = array_map('trim', $matches[0]);

print_r($matches);
```

This regex matches parts that begin with the number `1` then continues to match everything until again number `1` is found.